# XSLT <xsl:element> equivalent in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

When writing XML-compliant JSP, it is difficult to generate different HTML tags according to the input (e.g. when outputting the different tags in a `<table>`).

The standard solution is to use `if` or `choose` tags, but sharing code inside the HTML tag becomes a problem. E.g.

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}><th> <!-- 100 lines of code --> </th></c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}><td> <!-- 100 lines of code duplicated?! --> </td></c:when>
</c:choose>
```

XSLT offers an `<xsl:element>` tag which allows you to build a tag *and its attributes* with standard XML syntax. Is there such a tag in any tag library in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing this like?

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}"><th></c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}"><td></c:when>
</c:choose>
 <!-- 100 lines of code --> 
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}"></th></c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}"></td></c:when>
</c:choose>
```

---

If you want your markup to be valid XML; make use of a *custom tag* that wraps all the Java code you want to avoid duplicating. Your markup would then look something like

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}">
  <th>
   <my:customTag anyAttributes="th-related-values-if-any" ... />
  </th>
 </c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}">
  <td>
   <my:customTag anyAttributes="td-related-values-if-any" ... />
  </td>
 </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

---

Alternatively, the following hack (suggested by *[@Uooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1328300/uooo)*) can be used to pass XML validators.

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}"><c:out value="&lt;th&gt%" /></c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}"><c:out value="&lt;td&gt%" /></c:when>
</c:choose>
 <!-- 100 lines of code --> 
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'th'}"><c:out value="&lt;/th&gt%" /></c:when>
 <c:when test="${i.tag = 'td'}"><c:out value="&lt;/td&gt%" /></c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: This is not valid XML, which interferes with some automated tools I use.

Comment: @billc.cn you could use e.g. `<c:out value="&lt; th &gt;" escapeXml="true" />` instead of `<th>`, which will give you valid XML. However this would be a kind of a hack.

Comment: I eventually did something similar to @Uooo's comment. Since our XML reader is not configured to validate tags in HTML namespace, this hack kind of worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a seperate JSP containing your "100 lines of code" and include it.

Replace your `<!-- 100 lines of code -->` with:

```
<jsp:include page="hundredLines.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="beanParam" value="beanValue"/>
</jsp:include>
```

And in your `hundredLines.jsp`:

```
Bean can be used like ${beanParam}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. JSP requires knowing the tags when it builds its trees. That makes the operation of JSP more robust

However, you can address the duplicated code by factoring it into a separate JSP file and including it, depending on the implementation of JSP you are using.

Alternatively, you can create a JSP tag that holds the 100 lines of code. It is probably not worth while to do this.

Finally, you could, instead of using `th` and `td`, use styles on `td` to make `td` look like `th`. That would make the element look like

```
<td style="${i.tag == 'th' ? '' : 'font-style: bold; text-align: center;'}">
  100 lines of code
</td>
```

I know I don't have the style quite right, but you could use `styleClass` instead and play with it in your CSS.